# Is there a way to encode tkinter Entry fields as utf-8?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am messing around with tkinter for the first time and have a question. Is there a way to encode tkinter entry fields? Here is my code:

```py
my_username = Entry(window,width=10)
my_username.grid(column=1, row=0)

#a few lines that have nothing to do with username

username = my_username.encode('utf-8')
```

And here is the problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project.py", line 34, in <module>
    username = my_username.encode('utf-8')
AttributeError: 'Entry' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Is there a proper way to encode an entry field? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't encode the widget itself since encoding is a string operation and the widget isn't a string. You can encode the data you get *from* the widget, however.

```
username = my_username.get().encode('utf-8')
```