# Text widget in Tkinter not accepting Pashto writing that is a UTF-8 encoded language

Tags: python, tkinter, encoding, utf-8, text-widget

Pashto is a UTF-8 language, I am working with Tkinter library of python and make a Text box to write in it utf-8 languages like Pashto, but when I am writing in it, it does not work just show me question marks like ?????????.
How to define encoding for Text as UTF-8 to accept all the languages.
Please help me, I am really stuck with it.

textentry = Text(frame,  wrap=WORD, font="bold 14", pady=5, padx=5, encoding="utf-8")
I used to define it like that but I think Text widget does not have encoding property to define.
It raise an error (_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-encoding")

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61432533/is-there-a-way-to-encode-tkinter-entry-fields-as-utf-8) answer your question?